# how to get data of logged in users from Firestore with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

heys guys I want to get logged in user data from Firestore using react and firebase v9 but in the console I am getting data of all the users 
here my code:

```
const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");

useEffect(() => {
   onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        getDocs(usersCollectionRef, user.uid).then((snapshot) => {
          console.log(snapshot);
        });
      }
    });

  }, []);
```

I want to get the data of only logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of of fetching all the documents in the users collections, you can fetch a single document as long as you know the document ID. You can use [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc) to create a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) to that user's document and then use [`getDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdoc) to get that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid))
      console.log(snapshot.data())
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: what is the right way to have user state in react app using firebase auth? should I use context, react firebase hooks or is this method (onAuthStateChanged) enough to get user state through the app?