# How to retrieve the user's info that is currently logged in from Firestore/Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey guys I have a collection on Firestore `users` and each collection has `displayName`, `email`, and `uid` and trying to get the displayName of the user that is currently logged in.

At the moment the code below is fetching all the users correctly but not the specific user that logged in. The commented out code is kinda a solution that show around but I guess I am not doing it correctly. I have been trying for a while now and cant really find a way, it should be something simple but don't know what I am missing.

```
 const [users, setUser] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const users: any = []
      const db = getFirestore()
      const userRef = collection(db, 'users')
      // const userName = getAuth().currentUser?.displayName
      // const userDocument = query(userRef, where('displayName', '==', userName))
      // console.log('name', userName)
      try {
        const snapshot = await getDocs(userRef)
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          // const { displayName } = doc.data()
          users.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            // displayName,
          })
        })
        console.log(users)
        setUser(users)
      } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    })()
  }, [])
```

Comment: I just answered same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71860149/13130697). You can directly call `onAuthStateChanged()` in `useEffect()`. Also instead of fetching all the documents in the users collections, you can fetch a single document with `getDoc()`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need the logged in user's data / displayName from 'users' collection
2. You have already connected with firebase/firestore that means
   you are maintaining a valid firebase config file / credentials
3. If the above information is correct then this can be a solution for you

- Import `firebase` from the firebase config file
- Then get the current user's `uid` and userProfile

```js
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const currentUserProfile = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);
```

- Then you can get the required data in `useEffect` as required

```js
useEffect(() => {
    currentUserProfile.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            // const currentUserInfo = doc.data();
            const currentUserDisplayName = doc.data().displayName;
            // console.log(currentUserDisplayName)
            // now you can update your state with this value from here if required 
        })
        .catch((err) => {alert("Error in displaying Name!")})

}, [])
```

Comment: what is the right way to have user state in react app using firebase auth? should I use context, react firebase hooks or is method (onAuthStateChanged) enough to get user state through the app?